# My App DO NOT REQUIRE Access to basic info

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

My application does not require "access to basic info" and I think this is strange since I read that Facebook should display to the user that my application is requiring access to the basic info.

All what I see is this:

Post to Facebook as you
XXXXXX may post status messages, notes, photos, and videos on your behalf

and I button ALLOW / DONT ALLOW

I am just request extended permissions to post on the user wall. Normally I should also see that I would like to request the access to the user Basic Info, isnt it?

This is the code I use for Auth.

```
$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
$dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($app_url) . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'] ."&scope=publish_stream";
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you ask for *any* permission (in your case, posting on a user's wall (stream_publish)), the Facebook API automatically requests the basic permisson on your behalf.